Execute on mob with NBT regardless of the NBT value (1.19.2)
I'm trying to execute a command if a mob has the Owner NBT tag, regardless of who the owner is. How would I do this, if possible?
I'd like to be able to do something like
/execute as @e[nbt={Owner=""}]
or
/execute as @e[nbt={Owner="*"}].
Which don't work, as expected, but I'm hoping there's a way that I didn't think of or simply don't know.
I intend to make something that only affects players and tamed mobs. It doesn't matter who tamed the mob, as long as it is tamed it should be affected.

Admittedly, I don't know the specifics of the NBT format, but going by this post, it doesn't seem like this is possible.

@Hoppeduppeanut while similar, this doesn't seem to be the same thing I'm looking for. Rather the opposite, I believe? From what I understand they want to save a player's name to NBT one way or another. What I want is to check for an NBT tag that usually does mention a player (or rather, their UUID), but read it without filling in a specific player. I simply want to check the existence of the NBT on the entity, even if it's empty. I'd want to be able to do an if [entity] has [NBT container tag] then ...

Here is the command you probably want:
execute as @e if data entity @s Owner run <Command>

This will run if the if data is successful, it doesn't check for any specific value.
For example, when I tested this only the entity with the Owner nbt, in my case an item, ran the command, and not the player. As I don't have the nbt on myself.

Thanks! This exactly what I was looking for.
